# Match order-independent collection contents for Spock interaction

Tags: spock

Is it possible to match on a list, regardless of order for a Spock interaction?

For example, if I have the following method:

```
public void execute(List<User> users)
{
  List<User> admins = users.stream().filter(User::isAdmin).collect();
  worker.initAdmins(admins);
}
```

And I'd like to test that `worker.initAdmins` is being called with the users I expect as follows:

```
def test()
{
  setup:
    // initialize a list of Users, some admin some not
    Collections.shuffle(users)
  when:
    task.execute(users)
  then:
    1 * worker.initAdmins(expectedAdminList)
}
```

The issue is that my interaction isn't being matched because I have no way to guarantee the order of the List being passed in.  Is this possible to work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a working solution.  For anyone else it may help in the future:

`1 * worker.initAdmins({[it.containsAll(expectedAdminList)] && it.size() == expectedSize})`

Comment: It's ok, but not enough - check the size as well.

Comment: @Opal Definitely a good suggestion, I've updated the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could cast to a `Set` in the method invocation expectation:

```
1 * worker.initAdmins(expectedAdminList as Set)
```

Note, this assumes there are no duplicates in your incoming list to be reliable.